# boost could not find "vswhere" with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, compiler-errors

I'm trying to install boost_1_66_0 on windows 10.
I launched the  Bootstrap.bat to install the boost in windows and got such an error logs

```
could not find "vswhere"
###
### Using 'msvc' toolset.
###
```

I installed Visual Studio 2019 and added the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer" to System Path Variable.
But error is not resolved.

Comment: I'm just guessing. Are you using `command prompt` or `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019` ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).